# Issue with references after pc restart

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, assembly-references

Hi guys as title says i just restarted my pc and got this missing references issue, I dont know why I came into this trouble related to msil architecture, missings dlls, in code is not even recognize extensions methods, please help me guys.

I'm working in vs2015 with xamarin forms v 2.3.4.270
I've trying several things but none of them are working ...

Comment: Please take a minute to read what you wrote, and then ask yourself, "Is there any way a complete stranger on the internet will have any clue what I'm talking about?"  You haven't included any meaningful details or specifics, just vague references to unspecific errors and "several things" that you've tried to fix the problem.

Comment: Ty for the response @Jason I did read what I wrote and believe me I dont have any idea of which of the 300 errors that just appeared on my screen. Mention on the post, that's why I tried to abstract all the errors in msil architecture, and missing dlls because is something that maybe someone faced before, but again thx for the observation about next time I will try to be more accurate about